# d3 read .csv header programmatically

Tags: d3.js

How can I read a csv header and set it's attributes programatically from my d3.csv call?

Here is how I call now:

```
d3.csv("data/att2.csv", function(d) {
    return {
        Id: d.Id,
        ProposedMass: d["Proposed"],
        MostProbablyCompound: d["Most"],
        Probability: +d["Prob"],
        Entropy: d.E,
        Formula: d.For,
        IonAnnotation: d["I"]
    };
}, 
function(error, rows) {
    window["data"] = rows;    
});
```

What I want is to key all csv header (keys) and set it's values automatically (instead of making it manually, as one may see in my code Id:d.Id, etc.
Then, if my csv changes, I don't need to recode it.

Comment: Did you try `d3.keys(d[index])` !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for:

```
d3.csv("data/att2.csv", function(data) {

    return data;        

}, function(error, rows) {
  window["data"] = rows;

});
```

Then you can separate all keys using d3.keys as a function :)
Hope it helps someone else.